# Jenkins Parameterized Build upload file and save original file name

Tags: file-upload, parameters, jenkins

How to save uploaded file under original file name in Jenkins Parameterized Build "File Parameter"?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what problem you are having?

Comment: I have user who upload files let say some1.txt and some2.txt but I forced to specify filename in param. And I want to use same file names.

Answer (score 22):

You can get original file name from the parameter with the same name as the parameter name (file location field).

For example if the file location is `my_file` then you can rename it to original by executing:

```
mv my_file ${my_file}
```

Comment: This will also check if file exists, and make it executable: `[[ -f my_file ]] && mv my_file ${my_file} && chmod +x ${my_file} || echo "Skipping upload"`

Answer (score 2):

The "File" Parameter of the *Jenkins Parameterized Build* always gets the *same* name in your job.

We were able to sort-of-bypass this by specifying *two* parameters:

- One parameter is of type *File* - this gets the content to the file.
- Other parameter is of type *String* - this gets the original name of the file.

In our script, we took the file as we got it via the first parameter,
then *renamed* it as the second.
(the user had to *Paste* the same value to both of the fields...)

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned by [Nux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333296/nux) (and [James Ruskin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1112679/james-ruskin)), this issue was [resolved around 2011](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11326),
so you now have the ability to access the original file, in the following way:

If, for example, your File-Parameter is named ***File1***,
then your script gets the **content** of that file in `File1`
and it can **access the original file** by using the local parameter `${File1}`.

***I suspect it gets tricky when the script and the user are not on the same OS,

i.e.: the user writes a path in Windows and the script runs on a Unix***

Comment: Thanks. That what I did. I think this is Jenkins limitation. And someone needs to request this cool feature like use same file name. Then string param no needed and you couldn't make mistake in it.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if one parameter would point to the data and another would hold the original name of the file. We should open a change-request.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer by Nux, this has been addressed by https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11326 - now allowing you to get the original filename from the environmental value ${parameter_name}