# Jenkins how to set an enviorment variable to the original file name of the parametized build?

Tags: file, jenkins, file-upload, parameters, environment-variables

Imagine i have an file parametized build in jenkins.
my file location is:
[image]

Then iam going to upload a file to the build with the name File2.xlsx. i understood that the content of File2.xlsx will be moved to the file-location(File.xlsx). But the original name of the file is stored in Variable ${File.xlsx}
i now tried to assign the orginal file-name to an enviroment variable but it dosent seem to work:
[image]
Any ideas how this could be working
[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951833/jenkins-parameterized-build-upload-file-and-save-original-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Problem where the dots and slashes in the variable_name. The variable is only avaible in the subshell, so you have to store the variable in a props file and then call another inject enviroment parameter.